# New Supersymmetry Algebra

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, supersymmetry, lie-algebra, superalgebra

We know that SUSY generators commute with translation
$$
[P_\mu,Q_\alpha]=0
$$
I have some questions:

1. What is this equation physical meaning?
2. Is it possible to make "SUSY-like" generators that do not commute with translation? $[P_\mu,Q_\alpha]\ne0$
3. What are the consequences of such relation?